# Prevent MathJax to append version to included JS

Tags: javascript, configuration, mathjax

I can't prevent MathJax to append the version to each JS include?

To clarify, follows the snapshot from developer console:

[image: developer tool network console]

- **EDIT** Add a config.js not workin
- **EDIT 2** Change with a simpler solution but still not working plus snippet

One possible solution, as I see in the code, is to override the `cdnVersion` property.

Follow the snapshot from `MathJax.js` of the default value property:

```
MathJax.cdnVersion = "2.7.1";  // specifies a revision to break caching
```

As suggest from Mathjax documentation ( [http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/index.html](http://doc%20page) 
) you can use `MathJax.Hub.Config()` to do the job.

I tried with this config does not work:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    config: ["MMLorHTML.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX","input/MathML","output/HTML-CSS","output/NativeMML", "output/PreviewHTML"],
    tex2jax: {inlineMath: [["$$","$$"]]},
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js","mml2jax.js","MathMenu.js","MathZoom.js", "fast-preview.js", "AssistiveMML.js"],
    TeX: {
        extensions: ["AMSmath.js","AMSsymbols.js","noErrors.js","noUndefined.js"]
    },
  cdnVersion: null
});
```

Follows a demo snippet:

```js
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    config: ["MMLorHTML.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX","input/MathML","output/HTML-CSS","output/NativeMML", "output/PreviewHTML"],
    tex2jax: {inlineMath: [["$$","$$"]]},
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js","mml2jax.js","MathMenu.js","MathZoom.js", "fast-preview.js", "AssistiveMML.js"],
    TeX: {
        extensions: ["AMSmath.js","AMSsymbols.js","noErrors.js","noUndefined.js"]
    },
    cdnVersion: null
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js"></script>


$$ \frac{3}{4}x^2 $$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible because they're not settings defined in `config/default.js`, from [config documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/index.html)

> The various components of MathJax, including its input and output
>   processors, its preprocessors, its extensions, and the MathJax core,
>   all can be configured through the `config/default.js` file, or via a
>   `MathJax.Hub.Config()` call (indeed, if you look closely, you will see
>   that `config/default.js` is itself one big call to
>   `MathJax.Hub.Config()`). **Anything that is in `config/default.js` can be
>   included in-line to configure MathJax**.